# Prestashop broken after module PayPal installed

Tags: paypal, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-modules

I installed PayPal module on my Prestashop site with version 1.5, after that I received this error if I try to contact my web site:

```
Warning: require(/web/htdocs/www.safarino.it/home/modules/paypal/backward_compatibility/backward.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /web/htdocs/www.safarino.it/home/modules/paypal/paypal.php on line 127 Warning: require(/web/htdocs/www.safarino.it/home/modules/paypal/backward_compatibility/backward.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /web/htdocs/www.safarino.it/home/modules/paypal/paypal.php on line 127 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/web/htdocs/www.safarino.it/home/modules/paypal/backward_compatibility/backward.php' (include_path='.:/php5.6/lib/php/') in /web/htdocs/www.safarino.it/home/modules/paypal/paypal.php on line 127
```

How can I fixed them ?
I cannot remove this module because also web panel is broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your module folder in FTP from "paypal" to something else like "paypal.bak",
this way module will not be loaded at runtime and you'll get access again to your backoffice.

That said, I am not sure Paypal module is still compatible with Prestashop 1.5.

Consider upgrading Prestashop to 1.7 version (or at least 1.6) since 1.5 is over 6 years old and you will have other major issues other than Paypal sooner or later..

Comment: Thanks you very much, your suggestion fixed my issue. How can I update prestashop? To 1.6 version?

Comment: It's a painful job updating from such a old version - I suggest you to migrate your data in a empty 1.7 and re-configure the environment... You can start here => https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/basics/keeping-up-to-date/